# How to clear All the values in a TDBGrid

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to create an application with VB6 that contains a TDBGrid. My problem is how  can i clear All the values in this TDBGrid.

Comment: It depends. How is the TDBGrid getting its data? I.e. is it bound to a database, or an XArrayDB, or what? You find this out by looking at the value of the [`DataMode` property](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/default.htm#!datamodeproperty.htm).

Comment: The TDBGrid getting its data from XArrayDB

Answer (score 1):

Since the TDBGrid is getting its data from an XArrayDB, just use [Clear](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/default.htm#!clearmethodxarraydb.htm) then [ReBind](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/default.htm#!rebindmethod.htm):

```
'Delete all rows from the XArrayDB 
theXArrayDB.Clear 

'Tell grid to reload the data 
theTDBGrid.ReBind
```